# Anyone used mantis connect to submit a issue with an attachment?

Tags: c#, web-services, attachment, mantis

I'm having troubles adding an attachment to the mantis using mantis connect. I can attach a file to the issue, but when i download for instance an image, it always gives me an error when I try to open the image.

I've many ways of reading the file to an byte array always with no success.

Has anyone used the mantisconnect to submit an attachment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you've run into a bug which was fixed on 1.1.7: [mc_issue_attachment_add corrupts attachments](http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=10235)